# Using WMI (ManagementEventWatcher) to get a newly added devices handle

Tags: c#, wmi

I have the following code

```
public static class Events
{
    public static HardwareWatcher hardwareWatcher = new HardwareWatcher();
    public static event EventHandler<HardwareEvent> HardwareChangeDetected;
    public static event EventHandler<HardwareEvent> HardwareConnected;
    public static event EventHandler<HardwareEvent> HardwareDisconnected;
    public static event EventArrivedEventHandler DeviceAdded;
    public static event EventArrivedEventHandler DeviceRemoved;
}

public class HardwareWatcher
{
    public ManagementEventWatcher DeviceArrivedWatcher;
    public ManagementEventWatcher DeviceRemovedWatcher;
    public ManagementEventWatcher HardwareListener;

    public HardwareWatcher()
    {
        HardwareListener = new ManagementEventWatcher();
        HardwareListener.EventArrived += HardwareListener_EventArrived;
        HardwareListener.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 OR EventType = 3");
        HardwareListener.Start();

        DeviceArrivedWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
        DeviceArrivedWatcher.EventArrived += DeviceArrivedWatcher_EventArrived;
        DeviceArrivedWatcher.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'");
        DeviceArrivedWatcher.Start();

        DeviceRemovedWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
        DeviceRemovedWatcher.EventArrived += DeviceRemovedWatcher_EventArrived;
        DeviceRemovedWatcher.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'");
        DeviceRemovedWatcher.Start();
    }

    private void DeviceRemovedWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        HardwareEvent eArgs = new ODIF.HardwareEvent();
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
        eArgs.guid = new Guid((string)instance["ClassGuid"]);

        string hidString = string.Join("|", (string[])instance["HardwareID"]);
        string[] hidSectioned = hidString.Split(new string[] { "\\","|","&","_" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int vidIndex = Array.IndexOf(hidSectioned, "VID");
        int pidIndex = Array.IndexOf(hidSectioned, "PID");
        if (vidIndex > -1)
            eArgs.vid = hidSectioned[vidIndex + 1];
        if (pidIndex > -1)
            eArgs.pid = hidSectioned[pidIndex + 1];

    }

    private void DeviceArrivedWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        HardwareEvent eArgs = new ODIF.HardwareEvent();
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
        eArgs.guid = new Guid((string)instance["ClassGuid"]);

        string hidString = string.Join("|", (string[])instance["HardwareID"]);
        string[] hidSectioned = hidString.Split(new string[] { "\\", "|", "&", "_" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int vidIndex = Array.IndexOf(hidSectioned, "VID");
        int pidIndex = Array.IndexOf(hidSectioned, "PID");
        if (vidIndex > -1)
            eArgs.vid = hidSectioned[vidIndex + 1];
        if (pidIndex > -1)
            eArgs.pid = hidSectioned[pidIndex + 1];

    }

    private void HardwareListener_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        HardwareEvent eArgs = new ODIF.HardwareEvent();
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
        eArgs.guid = new Guid((string)instance["ClassGuid"]);

        string hidString = string.Join("|", (string[])instance["HardwareID"]);
        string[] hidSectioned = hidString.Split(new string[] { "\\", "|", "&", "_" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int vidIndex = Array.IndexOf(hidSectioned, "VID");
        int pidIndex = Array.IndexOf(hidSectioned, "PID");
        if (vidIndex > -1)
            eArgs.vid = hidSectioned[vidIndex + 1];
        if (pidIndex > -1)
            eArgs.pid = hidSectioned[pidIndex + 1];


    }

}

public class HardwareEvent : EventArgs
{
    public string vid { get; set; }
    public string pid { get; set; }
    public Guid guid { get; set; }
    public string instancePath { get; set; }
}
```

Which seems to work ok, but I need to figure out how to retrieve the device handle to open communication with it from within the WMI event. Would rather NOT use any additional libraries.

Comment: What type of devices are you watching for?

Comment: In theory, any, mostly HID though